# Bash Script not returning anything, using positional parameters

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, command-substitution

Running the script in-theory should output results per line depending on the arguments used

The scripts name is 'stdout', and have made it exacutable. I enter './stdout GOOGLE.COM' into the console and nothing happens

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "Results: [ cat whois_google.com.txt | grep $1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | sort -r]"
        exit 1
fi
```

There are no errors, the text file is a dummy file including simple fields such as 'Server Name: GOOGLE.COM.AR' and after running the command I'm hoping for an output of the different server names

Comment: Replace `[ cat ...]` with `$( cat ...)`.

Comment: you have `[ $# -lt 1 ]`, you should have something other than `-lt`.  Maybe `-ge` or `-eq`?  Once you're getting the expected `echo`, you can follow @Cyrus's correction to actually execute the subshell.

Comment: You really [don't need `cat` here at all.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: `exit 1` is usually an indication that there was an error. You want `exit 0` or just let the script run to its end, which returns the status code of the last external command which the script executed.

Answer (score 0):

if you pass an argument to your script it will never do anything... the `if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then` line of script is checking to see if the number of arguments is less than 1. Try changing to `-gt`.  Also a bad idea to call your script `stdout`, pick a name for what your script does.

Comment: Probably `-ge`, not? With `-gt`, it'll only work if there are 2 or more arguments. Alternatively, `if (( $# ))` is true for 1 or more arguments, false for 0.